# How to Load Test Application Life Cycle Management ( ALM ) application?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, httpwebresponse, loadrunner, web-testing

Recently we have created a new ALM 11.0 Infrastructure with Application/Database/Repository Servers all located at a single place (same geographical area).

ALM 11.0 application is hosted on the Application Server.

There are around 13 database projects in this ALM application which users can access. The physical files used during test runs (such as jpeg, png, xls, and pdf) are stored in the repository. On this environment we want to conduct load testing and performance testing.

We want to perform some user actions and estimate the response time’s from the server. Below are some of the user actions which can be considered.

1. In how much time is the user able to login into the application?
2. At a specific point of time how many users can simultaneously login into the application?
3. After logging into the application how much time is taken to enter each module? Module can be Dashboard, Defect, Requirements, Test Plan, and Test Lab?
4. How much time is required by the application in order to create new entities such as Test Script, Requirement, Test Set with a group of Test Instances, Dashboard report etc?
5. How much time is spent by the application in order to display few reports by accessing the files from the repository?
6. How much time is required by the application to associate requirement coverage with Test Script and Test Instance?
7. How much time is taken by the application to Log Out successfully?

I am unable to record the LOGIN part of ALM application using VuGen 11.0 Patch 4 using the Web [HTTP/HTML] protocol I am receiving

```
Initialization has failed. Contact your System Administrator
```

Upon further research I came to know that attached benchmark kit has been provided by the vendor and the scripts for logging into ALM are all pre-written and they have to be executed by customizing them through providing necessary parameter values related to our current environment.

I took the first script `WEB_GlobalLoginOut_In` I have provided the necessary parameter values like server name, project name, username, password etc. I have tried different manipulations on the provided script but the script replay is always failing.

Are there any tutorial or step by step instructions which I can follow so that I can keep moving with this ALM application recording using Vugen Tool? I am currently stuck at the Login Part itself.

Comment: Did you complete the LoadRunner tutorial in: Start-> Applications -> HP Software->HP LoadRunner -> Documentation -> Tutorial -> Tutorial - Print Version?

Comment: Hi Buzzy, Yes I completed the tutorial, I completed the work book, I have gone through motevich video tutorials, I have gone through Vuser 11 guide, I have through many blogs, I DID the home work, I am asking this question because it is really out of my understanding(knowledge),before asking this question tried to solve the requirement on my own several times.I even went through the forums and KB articles no where it is clearly explained how to acheive this requirement

Comment: Ok, Ok, don't be angry... Did you try the LR support forum: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF

Comment: yes Buzzy I tried in Support Forum as well as Customer Forum they referred to PSO but they did not provide me any starting point, By the way I am not angry may be sounded like that.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the LR Support forum post here, I want to see what were the answers there.

Comment: @ Buzzy: Please find the below URL's

Comment: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Customer/Performance-Testing-on-ALM-Application/m-p/6141631

Sub: Performance Testing on ALM Application? 

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Customer/How-to-record-the-Application-Life-Cycle-Management-software-for/m-p/6029815#M224

Sub: How to record the Application Life Cycle Management software for Performance Testing?

Comment: this forum is not related to the URL I posted above.

Comment: I posted in the forum which you provided , I did not recieve any answers.

Comment: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/Performance-Testing-on-ALM-Application/td-p/6141389

Comment: Hi Please let me know in case of any further advises.